# Java Array Object compile issue

Tags: java, arrays, object

The following code get's an error when compiled. I know it's missing something but I just can't figure out what.

```
public class Books {
    String title;
    String author;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Books[] myBooks = new Books[3];

        myBooks[0].title = "Learn Java";
        myBooks[1].title = "Java Development";
        myBooks[2].title = "Java Today!";
        myBooks[0].author = "S";
        myBooks[1].author = "Mr. S";
        myBooks[2].author = "SN";

        int x = 0;
        while (x < myBooks.length) {
            x = x + 1;
            System.out.print(myBooks[x].title);
            System.out.print(" by ");
            System.out.println(myBooks[x].author);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I see no *compilation* errors.  A *runtime* error, though...

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Books[] myBooks = new Books[3];
    myBooks[0] = new Books();
    myBooks[1] = new Books();
    myBooks[3] = new Books(); ....

Comment: Do you have a main method?
In Java, you need to have a method named main in at least one class.

Comment: I get an Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Books.main(Books.java:11). I'm reading the "What is a null point exception, and how to fix it" question that Makoto suggested.

Comment: That's also what I received when I compiled and ran this code.  You should reference the duplicate question linked here.

Comment: Specifically, you created an empty array and didn't put any `Book` objects in it.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
    while (x < myBooks.length) {
        x = x + 1;
        System.out.print(myBooks[x].title);
        System.out.print(" by ");
        System.out.println(myBooks[x].author);
    }
```

to

```
    while (x < myBooks.length) {
        System.out.print(myBooks[x].title);
        System.out.print(" by ");
        System.out.println(myBooks[x].author);
        x = x + 1;
    }
```

Consider case when `x=2` at srat of the loop. It becomes 3 first and then books[3] will throw Exception.

Other than that you have simply defined an array which is nothing but just references. You need to initialize all of them.

```
for(Books book : myBooks ) {
   book = new Books();
}
```

If you are not initializing the array they are just pointing to null and if you perform any operations on it like `myBooks[i].title` you will get NPE.

Comment: Um...no.  That doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: It may not be the issue you may be getting at compile time but it is an issue and you need to fix it. I see no compile time violations in your code.

Comment: I don't disagree that it's a problem, but that block of code isn't even reached in the program's lifecycle (yet).

Comment: Agreed. @user3638942 you need to initialize your array. Answer updated.